# GET size limit for Flash SWF, Air for Android, Desktop exe/app projectors urlRequest

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

What is the size limit on GET urlRequests for Flash-based environments?

I know browsers and servers have their respective limits but I'm wondering about ***local*** SWF, EXE or APP files.

What about AIR for mobile devices?

Comment: I just did a test and was able to send 3690 characters in the Flash IDE before errors started kicking in. This could be a limit on my server tho...